# Not able to fetch custom Metrics (for Azure Linux Virtual Machine) using Azure Monitor REST API

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

I have configured Diagnostic Settings and Insights to get the Custom Metrics. After configured, I get the Custom Metrics Namespace and Metrics also display the data.

[image]

But when I try to fetch the same metric data using the Azure Monitor REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) then I'm unable to fetch data because "Custom metric Namespace and Metric name" are not available for Linux Virtual Machine.

Example for Windows VM:
Metric Namespace for Windows VM: "Azure.VM.Windows.GuestMetrics"
Metric Name: "Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use"
So I can fetch custom metrics data for Windows Virtual Machine using the above metric namespace and metric name.

I want to fetch custom metrics data like: Memory used, Logical Disk Performance for linux virtual machine. Please help me to get out of this issue.

**How to get custom metrics data for linux virtual machine using REST API or Nodejs SDK?**

Comment: Could share your sample code of api you are trying

Comment: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/aztestgroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/az-vm-test-1/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2020-11-30T11:30:00.000Z/2020-12-02T11:30:00.000Z&interval=PT1M&metricnames=\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use&aggregation=Average&api-version=2018-01-01&metricnamespace=azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics`

Comment: **The above REST API, I'm calling to fetch the Custom Metric data for Windows VM. I'm facing the issue for Linux VM. Because to get custom metric I need to provide metric namespace, but for Linux VM I'm unable to get the metric namespace. So I'm unable to get custom metric data for linux VM.**